# Subsetting an R xts object by year returns data from February to January of following year

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a monthly data series formatted as an `xts` object with 361 months of data ending in 2016. Below is a sample.

```
Jan 2015 20.97
Feb 2015 13.34
Mar 2015 15.29
Apr 2015 14.55
May 2015 13.84
Jun 2015 18.23
Jul 2015 12.12
Aug 2015 28.43
Sep 2015 24.50
Oct 2015 15.07
Nov 2015 16.13
Dec 2015 18.21
Jan 2016 27.59
```

I'm trying to extract a subset with `VIXCLS["2015/"]`. When I get back the results the year starts on February of 2015 and ends on Jan of 2016.  I've also tried to extract a specific month (ex: `VIXCLS["2015-12-31]`) and I get back January 2015 data with the January time stamp.

```
VIXCLS['2015-12-31']
#          VIXCLS
# Jan 2016  27.59
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas as why this is happening.

Comment: Please post a `dput` of your data or of a sample. This will preserve the format and attributes.

Comment: … and see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a timezone issue. Your index is `yearmon`, which does not have a timezone. But your xts object may have a non-UTC timezone, which would cause conversion issues. For example, this xts object has my local timezone, so the subsetting works as you describe:

```
VIXCLS <- structure(c(20.97, 13.34, 15.29, 14.55, 13.84, 18.23, 12.12, 28.43, 24.5,
  15.07, 16.13, 18.21, 27.59), .Dim = c(13L, 1L), index = structure(c(1420070400, 
  1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 
  1438387200, 1441065600, 1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400),
  tzone = "", tclass = "yearmon"), class = c("xts", "zoo"),
  .indexCLASS = "yearmon", tclass = "yearmon", .indexTZ = "", tzone = "")
VIXCLS['2015/']
#           [,1]
# Feb 2015 13.34
# Mar 2015 15.29
# Apr 2015 14.55
# May 2015 13.84
# Jun 2015 18.23
# Jul 2015 12.12
# Aug 2015 28.43
# Sep 2015 24.50
# Oct 2015 15.07
# Nov 2015 16.13
# Dec 2015 18.21
# Jan 2016 27.59
```

But if I set the `indexTZ` to `"UTC"`, the issue goes away:

```
indexTZ(VIXCLS) <- "UTC"
VIXCLS['2015/']
#           [,1]
# Jan 2015 20.97
# Feb 2015 13.34
# Mar 2015 15.29
# Apr 2015 14.55
# May 2015 13.84
# Jun 2015 18.23
# Jul 2015 12.12
# Aug 2015 28.43
# Sep 2015 24.50
# Oct 2015 15.07
# Nov 2015 16.13
# Dec 2015 18.21
# Jan 2016 27.59
```

If you get a warning about the object timezone being different than the local timezone, you can suppress it using `options(xts_check_TZ=FALSE)`.

Also note that this is corrected in the development version of [xts on GitHub](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts). Index classes that do not have a timezone attribute are not allowed to have a non-UTC timezone.

Comment: Thanks.  The sub-setting function now works as expected.  However, as you pointed out it gives a warning message.  I found out this message can also be eliminated by setting Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC").